# How to get a live preview of data-img-src from a select form?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**tl;dr**

I have a dropdown list with the names of png symbols and would like to present a live preview of what the image looks like next to the dropdown before the user hits 'submit'.

**More detailed information:**

I have a leaflet.js map where the user can place markers. When the user does, a popup opens where a symbol for the marker can be choosen. This is where the dropdown menu sits and of course it would be nice to have a preview of the symbol. Especially as there are quite a few.

Initially I wanted to have an emoji-picker-style menu with different tabs for different categories of symbols. Alas, I hardly managed to find any libraries/code snippets as I do not want to insert unicode smileys but png symbols. What I did find was the [onesignal emoji-picker](https://github.com/OneSignal/emoji-picker) and the j[query.emojiarea plugin](https://github.com/GittiHab/jquery-emojiarea). But I failed to get them to work. Most likely because I'm a javascript beginner.

Then I tried to fall back to [rveras image-picker](https://github.com/rvera/image-picker) for a simpler but hopefully easier to implement way, but also failed at getting it to work.

Now I think, maybe the is a simple, pure jquery way of doing just a preview of the png next to a dropdown?

So you see, my question is actually three-fold:

1. Does anyone know a tutorial for dummies on how to get a emoji-picker
   style menu to work with png symbols? Or...
2. Can anyone show how to get the image-picker to work? Or ..
3. Can you tell me how I do this with vanilla jquery or javascript?

A problem might be that I'm operating within a leaflet popup that only allows html as content, so my code looks something like this:

```
 map.on('draw:created', function (event) {
      layer = event.layer,
          feature = layer.feature = layer.feature || {};        // Intialize layer.feature
          feature.type = feature.type || "Feature";             // Intialize feature.type
      props = feature.properties = feature.properties || {};    // Intialize feature.properties
      props.name = "my name";
      props.description = "my content";
      props.icon = "my icon";
      //picker()              //execute image picker
      var editablePopup = L.popup();
      var content = //Textfield for the marker name
                    '<span><b>Enter the name</b></span><br/><input id="shapeName" type="text"/><br/><br/>' +
                    //Dropdown to choose the icon
                    '<span><b>Choose an icon</b></span></br>'+
                    '<select id="shapeIcon" class="image-picker">'+
                    '<optgroup label="Cats">'+
                      '<option data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/220/200" value="1">Cute Kitten 1</option>'+
                      '<option data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/180/200" value="2">Cute Kitten 2</option>'+
                      '<option data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/130/200" value="3">Cute Kitten 3</option>'+
                      '<option data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/270/200" value="4">Cute Kitten 4</option>'+
                    '</optgroup>'+
                    '<optgroup label="Animals">'+
                      '<option data-img-src="http://lorempixel.com/220/200/animals/" value="5">Animal 1</option>'+
                      '<option data-img-src="http://lorempixel.com/180/200/animals/" value="6">Animal 2</option>'+
                      '<option data-img-src="http://lorempixel.com/130/200/animals/" value="7">Animal 3</option>'+
                      '<option data-img-src="http://lorempixel.com/270/200/animals/" value="8">Animal 4</option>'+
                    '</optgroup></select></br>'+
                    //Textarea (flexible in size as opposed to textfield) for the general description
                    '<span><b>Enter a description<b/></span><br/><textarea id="shapeDesc" cols="25" rows="5"></textarea><br/><br/>'+
                    //Save Button that call the saveIdIW functions
                    '<input type="button" id="okBtn" value="Save" onclick="saveIdIW()"/>';
      editablePopup.setContent(content);                 
      editablePopup.setLatLng(layer.getLatLng());
      editablePopup.openOn(map);
      drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
    })
```

If you want to see the whole code of the leaflet map, where I try this, see [here](https://fictionalmaps.com/wp-content/plugins/fictional-maps-handler/includes/js/fm.draw_map.js). Warning! It's likely quite messy...

PS: if you want to see the problem in action, go to [fictionalmaps.com](http://85.214.239.14/register/?subscription_plan=18&single_plan=yes), make a free account and hit "create map" in the user control center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this using [`on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/):

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
   $(document).on("change", "select", function() {
      let img = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("data-img-src");
      $("#preview").empty().append("<image src=" + img + "/>");
   });
});
```

```css
#preview {
  display:inline-block;
  position:absolute;
  margin-left:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="shapeIcon" class="image-picker">
  <optgroup label="Cats">
    <option data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/220/200" value="1">Cute Kitten 1</option>
    <option data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/180/200" value="2">Cute Kitten 2</option>
    <option data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/130/200" value="3">Cute Kitten 3</option>
    <option data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/270/200" value="4">Cute Kitten 4</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Animals">
    <option data-img-src="http://lorempixel.com/220/200/animals/" value="5">Animal 1</option>
    <option data-img-src="http://lorempixel.com/180/200/animals/" value="6">Animal 2</option>
    <option data-img-src="http://lorempixel.com/130/200/animals/" value="7">Animal 3</option>
    <option data-img-src="http://lorempixel.com/270/200/animals/" value="8">Animal 4</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
<div id="preview">

</div>
```

Update: As mentioned in the comments, this lead to problems if there is another `<select>` on the same page. This issue can be solved by target the `<select>` by its `id` in the `change` event instead of binding the function to all selects. In addition, the preview should already display an image on pageload. This can be done by setting the first option as `selected` and call `change()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("change", "#shapeIcon", function() {
    let img = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("data-img-src");
    $("#preview").empty().append("<image src=" + img + "/>");
  });

  $("#shapeIcon optgroup option:first").attr("selected", "selected");
  $("#shapeIcon").change();
});
```

```css
#preview {
  display:inline-block;
  position:absolute;
  margin-left:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="shapeIcon" class="image-picker">
  <optgroup label="Cats">
    <option data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/220/200" value="1">Cute Kitten 1</option>
    <option data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/180/200" value="2">Cute Kitten 2</option>
    <option data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/130/200" value="3">Cute Kitten 3</option>
    <option data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/270/200" value="4">Cute Kitten 4</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Animals">
    <option data-img-src="http://lorempixel.com/220/200/animals/" value="5">Animal 1</option>
    <option data-img-src="http://lorempixel.com/180/200/animals/" value="6">Animal 2</option>
    <option data-img-src="http://lorempixel.com/130/200/animals/" value="7">Animal 3</option>
    <option data-img-src="http://lorempixel.com/270/200/animals/" value="8">Animal 4</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
<div id="preview">

</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, while working flawlessly in your code snippet, it does not within my leaflet popup. No matter wether I place the jqeury code inside or outside the popup code, the preview div stays empty.

Comment: @Merion I've just updated the code in my answer. Please try again. The difference is that your select field is added dynamically, therefore the change event has to be passed from a parent static element like document to it.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you very much! Now to dissect every letter of your answer to actually understand why it works ;-)

Comment: @Merion Glad that I was able to help :) I added a link to on() in my answer as this might be the one thing that's not easy to understand. The important part is the section about "Delegated event handlers".

Comment: I found a further complication, @matthias_h: when I add another drowndown, the preview vanishes if the user selects an option from the second dropdown after choosing a symbol from the first. So, how can I make it, that the preview only listens to change to one select menu? I guess I need to work in the id="shapeIcon" somewhere, but can't seem to figure out how. And I can't find a tutorial or resource that I understand. I need to learch this stuff from scratch if I ever find the time... Side question: can I preload the preview so it shows something before the first change happens?

Comment: @Merion I've updated my answer with a solution for both issues.

Comment: Thanks, you're the best! The preview is now effectivly ignoring the other drowdown! The preloading does not work though, but that's no big deal. Maybe that's because the form lives in a popup and does not exist before the popup is opened. I'll try and wrap those two lines in a function and call it when the popup opens.